# Missing system settings icon when running fvwm after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: unity, upgrade, desktop-environments

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE POST!!   I've just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. If I use the default ubuntu desktop manager, gnome-control-center works fine.   However, when I use my preferred fvwm as a manager, I'm missing icons, as per many previous posts.

[image]

I also get the same errors that have been reported by many people

```
** (gnome-control-center:32407): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher gufw (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:32407): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:32407): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)
```

Under 14.04 this didn't happen:   I had access to all my icons using both the ubuntu and the fvwm desktop managers.     I've tried the various remedies proposed in other posts, but not surprisingly they aren't applicable to my case, because gcc works fine under the default ubuntu desktop manager.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: This seems normal. I'm under i3-wm and I see only those icons. And yes, if other people are reporting the exact same problems in other posts, then this is a duplicate. I'm pretty sure this is a Unity/Ubuntu-desktop-reliant problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by further trolling the web.    `unity-control-center` returns for 16.04 what `gnome-control-center`  returned in 14.04